# How to read a tuple of dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Say I have a a dictionary (e.g. `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}`).
Say I want to read several keys of the dictionary, but not all (e.g. I want to read `d['a']` and `d['c']`).

Here is the way I do it: `(val_a, val_c) = (d[key] for key in ('a', 'c'))`.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I'd argue `(val_a, val_c) = (d[key] for key in ('a', 'c'))` is very *pythonic* in nature

Comment: It does seem a little odd that you would iterate through the dict and store the results as a variable when you can just get the value right from the dictionary: `d['a']`

Answer (score 3):

Use `operator.itemgetter`.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> get_ac = itemgetter('a', 'c')
>>> get_ac(d)
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to yours, but slightly shorter using `map`.
(Note: Just as with your approach, the result of `map` is not actually a `tuple` but a generator that is *unpacked* into multiple variables.)

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> a, c = map(d.get, ('a', 'c'))
>>> a, c
(1, 3)
```